# How can I perform a LINQ Query and select?

Tags: c#, linq

I am running the following:

```
var abc = new adminModel();
string text = abc.AnswerType.SingleOrDefault(s => s.Value == "2");
string text0 = abc.AnswerType.Single(s => s.Value == "2").Text;
var text1 = (from a in abc.AnswerType 
  here a.Value == "2"
  select a.Text).SingleOrDefault();
```

Where AnswerType looks like this:

```
public class adminModel
{

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> AnswerType
    {
        get
        {
            return new[]
                {
                    new SelectListItem { Value = "1", Text = "1 answer" },
                    new SelectListItem { Value = "2", Text = "2 answers" },
                    new SelectListItem { Value = "3", Text = "3 answers" },
                    new SelectListItem { Value = "4", Text = "4 answers" },
                    new SelectListItem { Value = "5", Text = "5 answers" },
                    new SelectListItem { Value = "6", Text = "6 answers" },
                    new SelectListItem { Value = "7", Text = "7 answers" },
                };
        }
    }

}
```

But I am getting an error message saying that "Can't convert SelectListItem to string". Is there a way that I can just extract the Text from the SelectListItem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code `AnswerType.SingleOrDefault(s => s.Value == "2")` will return `SelectedListItem` instance, not a `string`.

If you need to get text the query would be:

```
string text = AnswerType.Single(s => s.Value == "2").Text;
```

or

```
string text = AnswerType
    .Where(s => s.Value == "2")
    .Select(arg => arg.Text)
    .SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: This returns the error "only assignment, call, increment, decrement and new object expressions can be used as a statement

Comment: @David H - I copy/pasted your code with `AnswerType` and checked. `text` was assigned with `2 answers` string.

Comment: It might be the way I am using AnswerType. I will add something to my question to show that.

Comment: @David H - I saw your update. Copy/pasted your code again. Commented `Topic` and `SubTopic` as those are not defined. Ran the code and `abc.AnswerType.Single(s => s.Value == "2").Text` returned `2 answers`.

Comment: I added some more details to the question. Maybe it's the way that I am setting up the AnswerType?

Comment: @David H - If you create a new project and copy/pate the code that you are showing you will see that it works, except the original line `string text = abc.AnswerType.SingleOrDefault(s => s.Value == "2");`
`

Comment: @Alex - You are right and it does work in a new project. Looks like I have another small problem for myself but your answer is correct. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
string text = AnswerType
        .Where(s => s.Value == "2")
        .Select(s=> s.Text)
        .SingleOrDefault();
```